# how to print "a/b" where a and b are numeric value in JavaScript. I dont want to print the resultant value

Tags: javascript

how to print "a/b" where a and b are numeric value in JavaScript. I dont want to print the resultant value

if a=5,b=10

Output: 5/10

I know how to solve in Java but in JavaScript the var datatype automatically detect the type of value and perform calculation. Removing the decimal points from the number.

Answer (score 2):

So just add them as strings.

```
var out = a + "/" + b;
```

or use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

```
var out = a.toString() + b.toString();
```